# Problems with silent install of IBM Data Studio 4.1.3

Tags: deployment, sccm, silent, ibm-data-studio

Iam working on a mass Deployment of IBM Data Studio 4.1.3 via SCCM. But in the tests the isntallation fails with the following message:

Failed to write into registry in phase Install at path "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\IBM\OQT\IBM Data Studio\Install Path"

Iam using an extended version of the Powershell App Deployment Toolkit.

The script is executed as System-user, so it is clear that it cant be written to HKCU. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this issue?

I already packaged Data Studio 4.1.1 and there were no such problems.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this a powershell error in the script created by the app deployment toolkit or an error of the original msi/exe ? (also system account can write to HKCU without problem it is just that each user has their own personal hkcu so no other user would see it but it's not any kind of access rights problem)

Comment: It is an error from the Installer. As far as I know when it is executed by NT Authority System it cant write to HKCU, simply because it is not a user and does not have a User-part in the registry.

Comment: System is for the most part a user like any other although there are small (sometimes problematic) differences. If you open regedit there will be a key "HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT" which is what will be mapped as HKCU for the system account. You can check this using psexec or paexec run cmd as system start regedit (must be closed before) modify hkcu close regedit, start as user again and check .DEFAULT. With that in mind the error really is very strange. There is a speciality that .DEFAULT is loaded from system32 which may be redirected if you use a sccm program but I don't see thus breaking an msi

Answer (score 0):

how did you deploy it? Is it "install for system"? If yes, try "install for user" and check the results.

Best Regards,
Ray